# How do we disable this button with no compiler error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to improve myself in Objective-C and what I am on about is now modifying and changing and existed project. I did everything I wanted expect one thing. Theres an info button in my program and it doesnt related with .xib file. I tried to remove it but always my main.m gave error like SIGABRT (int retval thing.)

Here is the thing what I want to modify

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG51s.png   // The picture of my program and info button

I am trying to remove the (i) button on the right-down corner.

Here's my code

```
This is my RootViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;  //Silinecek
    MainViewController *mainViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *mainViewController;

@end

This is my RootViewController.m

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize mainViewController;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    self.mainViewController = viewController;
    [viewController release];

    [self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton];
}
```

and also I tried to modify my AppDelegate h and m. Here they are ;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RootViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;

@end

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize rootViewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    [window addSubview:[rootViewController view]];
    //[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
/*
- (void)dealloc {
    [rootViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
*/
```

What should I do for removing that info button in my View. Thanks for the any tips

And if you are interested in this is the whole algorithm : http://pastebin.com/hHQkQYS6

Comment: did u remove     [self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton];
And it is mentioned as IBOutlet in the .h.. are you sure it is not thr on the xib?

Comment: Yes sir, I did it. But I get an error in main.m file which is

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(nil, nil, nil, nil); //I got error here
 [pool release];
        return retVal;
}
 and its the error =

http://pastebin.com/JBU9pN2J

Comment: The exception says that you're still referencing `infoButton` in your XIB. You need to find out where in your XIB(s) and remove that reference.

Comment: http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/1359/screenshot20120116at143.png

Its nowhere to be honest :/ Disabled every references and tried them one by one :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the control linked somewhere in your xib file? It is declared as an `IBOutlet` control. Usually when I have these controls I will use the GUI link this control in some way (I can't remember what exactly as I have not done Obj-C in a long time). But I would definitely have a look around you xib file (as well as removing  `[self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton];`

Comment: I looked at everywhere but I couldnt find it, disabled everything and reactivated one by one but still I cannot find the point between my ´XIB file´ and ´infoButton´

Comment: Is there an object explorer type interface you can use with XCode which shows every object you have on the XIB?

Comment: http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/1359/screenshot20120116at143.png

These are my objects and references. and this is the full algorithm http://pastebin.com/hHQkQYS6

I am checking Object Explorer right now

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps the info button is hiding behind your view? Maybe you could make another XIB and copy the contents of your existing one in there to see if the info button is there? I am sure I have had this problem once before, and I think a quick restart of XCode fixed it for me. But I am sure there is something more to this

Comment: I've tried it , remade the XIB but gives the same problem.That is really annoying. I dont really get it. Even feel free to check my whole project... :/ And thanks a lot for your answers. 
This is the project...:

http://www.megaupload.com/?d=Z8F4HDX7

Comment: I won't be able to check the project, but I do hope you manage to find out the problem. If I think of anything I'll let you know

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much! I am still on it but not a single progress.

Comment: @user1134994: Have you *cleared* your project (Cmd-K) lately? The `infoButton` is still mentioned in `DerivedData/Password/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MainWindow.nib`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception mentions:

```
[<RootViewController 0x4b9ab20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key infoButton.
```

The call stack shows that it is thrown by UINib. So this is happening during nib load. So check for all objects present, carefully,  in the nib and remove the info button

Comment: I have checked them all, but cant even find anything about infoButton :/  Should I completely rewrite it to a new project?

http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/3397/screenshot20120116at145.png